# Is it possible to set style color size

Tags: javascript, coding-style

Is it possible to set style,color,size of `javascript:popups` without using div,span etc.

Just using `javascript:popup`, how  we  can achieve it?

Answer (score 4):

Nope that's not possible, you will have to apply styles to some *element*. You can't do with `javascript:popup`.